# Using a specific URL in XMLHttpRequest, return NetworkError: A network error occurred

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, xmlhttprequest

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
if (!xmlhttp) {
    alert ("XMLHttpRequest create error");
}
xmlhttp.open ("GET", "http://127.0.0.10/advert/123", false);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        console.log (xmlhttp.status);
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            console.log (xmlhttp.responseText);
        } else {
            alert ("Error");
        }
    }
};
xmlhttp.send ();
```

The specific URL is '//host/advert/???'. Like:

//127.0.0.12/advert/123

//127.0.0.12/advert/test

And more...

Only using like this Url, Mistakes will come up.

The specific URL env is PHP+APACHE(rewrite), Code like this：

### index.php

```
echo 123;
exit;
```

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing usage of synchronous and asynchronous requests.

If you're passing `false` as 3rd parameter to `open` method, meaning that request should be synchronous (why, btw?), then you should process it like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.10/advert/123", false);
xmlhttp.send(null);

if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
  console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
```

Additional information: [Synchronous and asynchronous requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is only a demo to test whether a request has been made, that is to say, 'xmlhttp.status == 200'. I've found the problem. Damn plugin Adblock = =`